# CodeIgniter view not loading and white screen displayed instead

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been debugging this piece of code for hours now without success. All I'm trying to do is get a view to load. Instead of it loading, I get a white screen and no error messages anywhere.

Here's the code from the controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    //echo "we made it to the function";
    public function login_form()
    {
        $this->load->view('login_form');
    }

    public function login_submit()
    {
        print_r( $_POST );
        $this->load->model('Usermodel', 'users');
        $match = $this->users->authenticate_user( $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] );
        if( $match )
        {
            echo "User exists in database!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Email or password is wrong, bretheren!";
        }
    }
}
```

The important part is the "function login_form". Here is the code for that view:

```
<form action="<?php base_url() ?>welcome/login_submit" method="post">
    <label>
        email:
        <input id="email" name="email" />
    </label>
    <label>
        password:
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Log me in!" />
</form>
```

This is the link I'm using in my browser to get to the page: 
localhost/intranet/index.php/welcome/login_form

The code all looks fine to me and I just can't seem to figure out where the program is breaking. Does anybody have any ideas?

EDIT: I took out the shorthand but I have the same problem.

Comment: 1. Try to get the php_error.log from your MAMP/XAMP/LAMP server. 2. Otherwise, let's go debugging all the way : Delete all the PHP in your view, does it work ? No ? Then in `function login_form()` comment your `load->view` and put `echo "hello"`. Does it work ?

Comment: Does your server allow php shorttags?  Change your form action to `<?php base_url() ?>welcome/login_submit`.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use the shorthand, `<?=`, with CodeIgniter.

Comment: Interesting... when I deleted the entire form and replaced it with an h1, the h1 showed up fine. So it's not in the controller. What could the issue be with the form? Why would that cause php to break?

Comment: See last two comments before yours!

Comment: Thanks for your responses everyone. I removed the shorthand but it still won't show.

Comment: `echo base_url()` is missing the `echo`.  And have you loaded the URL Helper anywhere?

Comment: url helper? I'm sorry, I'm a newbie. I don't know what that is.

Comment: [Then take an hour to read the entire documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/index.html). You cannot use `base_url()` without the URL Helper! http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You're missing an `echo`...

```
<?php echo base_url() ?>
```

2)  To use `base_url()`, you also need to load the URL Helper someplace.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

3)  I strongly recommend reading the entire documentation, including the simple demos & tutorials, before starting a CodeIgniter project...

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

4)  Although you can use PHP short-tags (as per your server config), they're not recommended.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#short-open-tags

Answer (score 1):

You have to either enable the URL Helper in your configuration, or in the controller if you want to use the base_url() function:

```
$this->load->helper('URL');

<form action="<?php base_url() ?>welcome/login_submit" method="post">
```

should be

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/login_submit" method="post">
```

OR Shorthand if you configure it properly:

```
<form action="<?=base_url() ?>welcome/login_submit" method="post">
```

Noiticed the post about not being able to use shorthand with CodeIgniter and yes you can, I've just completed a project where we used shorthand. It's just how you configure your php.ini

```
<?= is just short for <?php echo
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using codeigniter so why not use it's all functionality. you can create form in codeigniter like this

So you no need to use **base_url** or so and it is the right method to use in codeigniter.

```
   <?php echo form_open("welcome/login_submit",array('method'=>'post')); ?>
<label>
    email:
    <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'email','id'=>'email')); ?>
</label>
<label>
    password:
    <?php echo form_password(array('name'=>'password','id'=>'password')); ?>
</label>
<?php
    echo form_button(array('type'=>'submit','value'=>'Log me in!'));
    echo form_close(); ?>
```